# Azure AD to forge rock user sync

Tags: azure-active-directory, openam, forgerock

I want to sync users from Azure AD to Forgerock open. Whenever users are created/deleted in Azure AD.  I want the users to be created/deleted in forge rock open.  I have established the SAML federation between forge rock and Azure AD.  Any suggestions on how this can be done.

Comment: If you use SAML2 'auto-federation' , you could at least generate a user profile on OpenAM side when the SAML flow succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAM is not able to actively sync any users. OpenIDM is the Forgerock tool for syncing/provisioning users. However, I'm not sure if there is a connector for (live-)syncing Azure AD, but you will probably find it out if you plan to use OpenIDM.

What should probably be possible is to use JIT-Provisioning to store those users logging in via federation to an LDAP/OpenDJ userstore. But that means users will only be updated when they login (and thus will never be deleted).